# Remove second last element of a list Pandas Dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have this problem, I would like to be able to remove second last-element of a list but keeping all the other elements.

I have this initial dataframe:

```
    Traceroute_1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.2', '10.0.12.10', '10.0.12.100']
    ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.13.10', '10.0.13.100']
    ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.1.26', '10.0.14.10', '10.0.14.100']
    ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.5', '10.0.22.10', '10.0.22.100']
    ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.9', '10.0.23.10', '10.0.23.100']
    ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.18', '10.0.24.10', '10.0.24.100']
    ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.23', '10.0.25.10', '10.0.25.100']
    ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.7.6', '10.0.3.5', '10.0.33.10', '10.0.33.100']
```

The result I would like to get in another column called "Traceroute_2" is this:

```
Traceroute_2
--------------------
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.2',  '10.0.12.100']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.13.100']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.1.26', '10.0.14.100']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.5', '10.0.22.100']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.9', '10.0.23.100']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.18', '10.0.24.100']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.23', '10.0.25.100']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.7.6', '10.0.3.5', '10.0.33.100']
```

As you can see, all the second-last elements of each list are removed but all the other values remain.

I tried this:

```
dfDef1["Traceroute_2"] = [el[:-2] for el in dfDef1["Traceroute_1"]]
```

but it comes out:

```
Traceroute_2
----------------------
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.2']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.1.26']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.9']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.18']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.23']
['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.7.6', '10.0.3.5']
```

This is my Code:

```
import pandas as pd

dfDef1 = pd.DataFrame({'Traceroute_1':
    [
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.2', '10.0.12.10', '10.0.12.100'],
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.13.10', '10.0.13.100'],
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.1.26', '10.0.14.10', '10.0.14.100'],
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.5', '10.0.22.10', '10.0.22.100'],
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.9', '10.0.23.10', '10.0.23.100'],
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.18', '10.0.24.10', '10.0.24.100'],
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.23', '10.0.25.10', '10.0.25.100'],
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.7.6', '10.0.3.5', '10.0.33.10', '10.0.33.100']
    ]
})

dfDef1["Traceroute_2"] = [el[:-2] for el in dfDef1["Traceroute_1"]]
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with `series.str` slicing:

```
dfDef1['Traceroute_2_new'] = (dfDef1['Traceroute_1'].str[:-2] 
                             + dfDef1['Traceroute_1'].str[-1:])
```

Comment: Interesting the `series.str` slicing can be used to slice a list of strings instead of just on a string.  I can't find any document stating such usage.  Can you point me to any online doc or guidelines on such usage?  Thanks!

Comment: @SeaBean the docs for [`series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) say this is just a vectorized method for how you will use a str method normally, so `"ABC"[-2:]` returns `BC` and `['A','B','C'][-2:]` returns `['B', 'C']` , imagine thats what happens but as a series

Comment: Very smart usage!  Thanks for the explanation!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

el[:-2] is taking everything from start until second to last element (excluded) and leaving the rest.

Try:

```
for i in dfDef1["Traceroute_1"]:
    i.pop(-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script, you are selecting all elements until the 3rd counting from the last.

Maybe with this small change to your script you are set:

```
dfDef1["Traceroute_2"] = [el[:-2].extend(el[-1]) for el in dfDef1["Traceroute_1"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove second to last item in the list:

somelist[:-2]+somelist[len(somelist)-2+1:]